# How to use conditional operator in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In many places I'm setting modified by, created by etc:

```
const test = this.state.isValueEdited
? {
  modifiedById: getLoggedInUser().userId,
}
: {
 // TODO
};
```

How could I check if `getLoggedInUser` has some value, than access `.userId`.. otherwise lets set `null`.

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also using the `ternary operator`

```
 modifiedById: getLoggedInUser() ? getLoggedInUser().userId : null
```

To avoid executing twice

```
const evaluation = getLoggedInUser()

{modifiedById: evaluation ? evaluation.userId : null}
```

Comment: This will call `getLoggedInUser()` twice. Thats inefficient & might cause unwanted sife effects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use logical OR `||`

```
modifiedById: ( getLoggedInUser() || { userId: null } ).userId
```

When the value returned from the getLoggedInUser returns falsy value the `{userId : null}` will act as default value

This expects value returned from getLoggedUser is falsy value in case it fails the condition

Comment: can you explain this line please `getLoggedInUser() || { userId: null }` This means even if userId is null try to access it ? or ?

Comment: Neat! Not the biggest fan of this syntax but it sure gets the job done

Comment: @Roxy'Pro when the value returned from the `getLoggedInUser` is falsy than only `{userId: null}` will come into picture, logical OR start evaluating expression from left and stop once it finds true value, if none of the value is true it returns the last value from expression, so here in `getLoggedInUser` returns falsy value than only the `{userId: null}` will be used else the value returned from function will be used

Comment: Down voter care to comment :/

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the user first, then you can use the `&&` operator to get the `userId` only if `user` returns truthy. `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, 0, `NaN` are falsy values

```
const user = getLoggedInUser() || null;

const test = this.state.isValueEdited ? ({
  modifiedById: user && user.userId,
}) : ...
```

If `getLoggedInUser` already returns `null` when the user is not logged, you can omit the `|| null`